# Possible error in the proof of Proposition 17.13 in Royden

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am reading Royden Fitzpatrick's text on Real Analysis ($4^{\text{th}}$ Edition) and have a question regarding the proof of Theorem Proposition 17.13 (p. 354).

**Relevant definitions:**

> A non-empty collection $\mathcal{S}$ of subsets of a set $X$ is called a *semiring* provided whenever $A$ and $B$ belong to $\mathcal{S}$, then $A\cap B\in\mathcal{S}$ and there is a finite disjoint collection $\{C_{k}\}_{k = 1}^{n}$ of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ for which $$A-B 
>  = \bigcup_{k = 1}^{n}C_{k}.$$ Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a collection of subsets of a set $X$ and $\mu:\mathcal{S}\rightarrow[0, \infty]$ a set function. Then $\mu$ is called a *premeasure* provided $\mu$ is finitely additive and countably monotone. That is, whenever $\{E_{k}\}_{k = 1}^{n}$ is a finite disjoint collection of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ and $\bigcup_{k = 1}^{n}E_{k}$ also belongs to $\mathcal{S}$, then $$\mu\Big(\bigcup_{k = 1}^{n}E_{k}\Big) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n}\mu(E_{k}),$$ and whenever a set $E\in\mathcal{S}$ is covered by a countable collection $\{F_{k}\}_{k = 1}^{\infty}$ of sets in $\mathcal{S}$, then $$\mu(E)\leq\sum_{k 
>  = 1}^{\infty}\mu(F_{k}).$$

Proposition 17.13 is stated as follows:

> Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a semiring of subsets of a set $X$. Define $\mathcal{S}'$ to be the collection of unions of finite disjoint collections of sets in $\mathcal{S}$. Then $\mathcal{S}'$ is closed with respect to the formation of relative complements. Furthermore, any premeasure on $\mathcal{S}$ has a unique extension to a premeasure on $\mathcal{S}'$.

**Question:**

My question is regarding the proof of the fact that $\mu'$ is countably monotone.

> Let $E = \bigcup_{j = 1}^{m}A_{j}\in\mathcal{S}'$, where the union is disjoint and each $A_{j}$ belongs to $\mathcal{S}$. Let $\{E_{k}\}_{k = 1}^{\infty}$ be a collection of sets in $\mathcal{S}$ covering $E$. For each $j$, $A_{j}$ is covered by $\bigcup_{k = 1}^{\infty}(A_{j}\cap E_{k})$ and therefore, by the countable monotonicity of $\mu$, $$\mu(A_{j})\leq\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{j}\cap E_{k}).$$ Thus, by the finite monotonicity of $\mu$, \begin{align}\mu'(E) &=  \sum_{j = 1}^{m}\mu(A_{j})\leq \sum_{j = 1}^{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{j}\cap E_{k}) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{j = 1}^{m}\mu(A_{j}\cap E_{k})\\
> &\color{red}{=}\color{red}{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mu(E\cap E_{k})\leq\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\mu'(E_{k}).}\end{align}

My question is regarding the part of the equation highlighted in red. It is not clear to me that $E\cap E_{k}\in\mathcal{S}$ and thus the expression $\mu(E\cap E_{k})$ does not make sense. I believe that the term should instead be $\mu'(E\cap E_{k})$ and the last inequality should be obtained by proving that $\mu'$ is monotonic as follows:

Let $A, B\in\mathcal{S}'$ such that $A\subseteq B$. Then $B = (B-A)\cup A$ and since $B-A\in\mathcal{S}'$, we have $\mu'(B) = \mu'(B-A)+\mu'(A)\geq \mu'(A)$.

Is this line of reasoning correct? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I agree with you that $\mu'$ should be used instead of $\mu$ since $E \in S$. Anyways your last argument looks fine.

Comment: @ムータンーオ thanks for the feedback!